# why my spider is not executing the parse function but with another link it works?

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to extract some data from this page, but the parse function is not executed, I try to put another URL like the one of google.com and is executed but with the page that I need it does not

```
import scrapy
from datetime import date
from osp_scraper.spiders.CustomSpider import CustomSpider


class PrincetonSpider(CustomSpider):
    name = "princeton"

    # year = date.today().year
    # month = date.today().month
    # day = date.today().day

    # start_urls = [f'https://blackboard.princeton.edu/webapps/blackboard/execute/viewCatalog?type=Course&command=NewSearch&searchField=CourseId&searchOperator=Contains&searchText=_&dateSearchOperator=LessThan&dateSearchDate_datetime={year}-{month}-{day}+9%3A33%3A00']
    start_urls = ['https://blackboard.princeton.edu/webapps/blackboard/execute/viewCatalog?type=Course']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('--------------------------------')
        courses = response.xpath('//*[@id="listContainer_databody"]/tr')
        for course in courses:
            print(course.xpath('td[1]/span[2]/text()').get())
            input()
            yield response.follow(
                url=course.xpath('th/a/@href').get(),
                callback=self.search_syllabus
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
custom_settings = {
        **CustomSpider.custom_settings,
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
    }
```

I put that and now works